# Can I group / aggregate elements in a list (or dict) comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples, as shown below:

```
[
    (1, "red")
    (1, "red,green")
    (1, "green,blue")
    (2, "green")
    (2, "yellow,blue")
]
```

I am trying to roll up the data, so that I can get the following dict output:

```
{
    1: ["red", "green", "blue"]
    2: ["green", "yellow", "blue"]
}
```

Notes are: the strings of colours are combined for the primary key (the number), and then split into a list, and de-duped (e.g. using `set`).

I'd also like to do the inverse, and group by the colours:

```
{
    "red": [1],
    "green": [1, 2]
    "yellow": [2]
    "blue": [1, 2]
}
```

I can clearly do this by looping through all of the tuples, but I'd like to try and do it with list / dict comprehensions if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use  `collections.defaultdict`:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> lis = [                            
    (1, "red"),
    (1, "red,green"),
    (1, "green,blue"),
    (2, "green"),
    (2, "yellow,blue"),
]
>>> dic = defaultdict(set)       #sets only contain unique items
for k, v in lis:
    dic[k].update(v.split(','))

>>> dic
defaultdict(<type 'set'>,
{1: set(['blue', 'green', 'red']),
 2: set(['blue', 'green', 'yellow'])})
```

Now iterate over `dic`:

```
>>> dic2 = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in dic.iteritems():
    for val in v:
        dic2[val].append(k)
...         
>>> dic2
defaultdict(<type 'list'>,
{'blue': [1, 2],
 'green': [1, 2],
 'yellow': [2],
 'red': [1]})
```

Comment: where's the comprehension?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without defaultdict.

```
>>> input = [
...     (1, "red"),
...     (1, "red,green"),
...     (1, "green,blue"),
...     (2, "green"),
...     (2, "yellow,blue")
... ]
>>> result1 = {s[0]: set(s[1].split(',')) for s in input}
>>> for num, cols in input:
...     result1[num].update(cols.split(','))
... 
>>> print(result1)
{1: {'red', 'green', 'blue'}, 2: {'green', 'yellow', 'blue'}}
>>> 
>>> result2 = dict((k, []) for k in set.union(*result1.values()))
>>> for k,v in result1.items():
...     for val in v:
...         result2[val].append(k)
... 
>>> print(result2)
{'red': [1], 'green': [1, 2], 'yellow': [2], 'blue': [1, 2]}
>>>
```

This is not necessarily better than the solution using defaultdict. Also, this is not pure comprehension, but uses comprehension as part of the solution.

Answer (score -2):

One line solution to generate counts of the unique elements, using dict comprehensions:

`X = [1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,2,3,2,4,2,5,3,4,3,5,4,5,5]`

`Xagg = {xx: sum([int(y==xx) for y in X]) for xx in set(X)}`

`Xagg`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to provide more explanation to your answers. See [How to answer page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for help in improving your answer.